# timestamp issue python3 mogoengine

Tags: django, mongodb, python-3.4

There is a issue related to timestamp (miliseconds) that we save date in the form of timestamp with data type is IntField using mongoengine (python ORM for mongodb) it's save properly but when we retreive the timestamp from the db it will automatically changed.

e.g.

> timestamp in db: "created_at" : NumberLong(1436926770000)
>
> timestamp return: NumberLong(1436955292000) always return the current time.

We are using Python3 dJango with mongoengine.

Any idea? Your help is appreiciated.

Comment: Not an issue with MongoEngine. Your code will be at fault. Show your code.

Comment: It could be related to  timezone settings in your project. Show your timezone settings as well.